# Merging columns in a time series dataset where most columns are null (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data set generated by posting events as a user progressively fills out a form (simplifying the example):

```
 sess_id   ts   col1   col2   col3   col4
  1         1   hello   
  1         2           world
  1         3                 I'm
  1         4                        fine
```

I want to transform this into

```
 sess_id    col1   col2   col3   col4
    1       hello  world  I'm    fine
```

I.e., take only the last value and concatenate the row window based on sess_id.

I'm totally blanking on how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select sess_id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
from t
group by sess_id;
```

Comment: D'uh! Thank you. Any way to do it based on the last `ts` rather than `max()`?

Comment: @metalaureate . . . I don't know what you mean by "last ts".  Perhaps you need to ask a new question.  This query answers the question you asked here.

Comment: @metalaureate change `max(col1)` to `(array_agg(col1 order by ts desc) filter(where col1 is not null))[1]`.

Comment: @AdamKG yes. that is what I was looking for. Thank you!